# Convertir una hora de tipo LocalTime a Segundos

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente código en el cual creo un objeto con determinados valores.
Uno de esos valores es un LocalTime el cual indica la duración de una carrera.

El problema es que ese valor lo necesito equivalente a segundos.

Investigando por JavaDoc me encontré con la función "ofSecondOfDay" la cual al aplicarla me hace lo inverso a lo que necesito, es decir; Le indico segundos y me los traduce a horas:minutos:segundos equivalentes.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Carrera c1 = new Carrera("Pekín", LocalTime.of(00, 40, 38), 110230);
```

Como extra había estado intendo cosas del tipo;

```
System.out.println(c1.ofSecondOfDay(c1.getDuracion())); //Duracion hace referencia al LocalTime.
```

ó

```
System.out.println(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(c1.getDuracion()));
```

Os agradecería mucho la ayuda.

PD: Sé que puedo separar segundos, minutos y horas, multiplicar y de allí sacar los segundos totales del tiempo. pero se que tiene que haber una manera de no hacerlo manual, de ser así me gustaría saberla. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar el [Enum ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) junto con el método [`until`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) de LocalTime.

Un ejemplo de uso sería el siguiente:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class pruebaLocalTime{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Instanciamos un punto de incio
        LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(00,00,00);
        // Instanciamos nuestro tiempo (final)
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(00,40,38);
        // Usamos 'until' para calcular el tiempo desde inicio hasta final
        // la unidad que usaremos será 'SECONDS'
        long segundos = start.until(end, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Segundos: " + segundos);
    }
}
```

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando. Esto es bastante flexible, sin realizar cálculos manuales.

**NOTA**

Asumo que usas Java 8.

Comment: No conocía ese método, esperaba una modificación al ofSecondsofDay pero la respuesta que has dado me funciona de 10. Gracias Mauricio.